# displaying percentage downloaded with cordova file transfer

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm able to download files to devices with the below script. and what i want to do know is to be able to show the percentage downloaded in the view.

```
downloadImage() {

    this.platform.ready().then(() => {

      const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.Transfer.create();

      const audiolocation = `http://myweb.com/files`+this.audio_download;

      fileTransfer.download(audiolocation, this.storageDirectory+'downloads').then((entry) => {
        const alertSuccess = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: `Download Succeeded!`,
          subTitle: `Audio was successfully downloaded to: ${entry.toURL()}`,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });

        alertSuccess.present();

      }, (error) => {

        const alertFailure = this.alertCtrl.create({
          title: `Download Failed!`,
          subTitle: `was not successfully downloaded. Error code: ${error.code}`,
          buttons: ['Ok']
        });

        alertFailure.present();

      });

    });

  }
```

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/#properties

Answer (score 0):

The file transfer has onProgress method. Refer this [link](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.3.0/cordova/file/filetransfer/filetransfer.html)

```
var fileTransfer= new FileTransfer();

fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
    var percent =  progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100;
    percent = Math.round(percent);
    console.log(percent);
};

//fileTransfer.download(...); // or fileTransfer.upload(...);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i get this error Property 'onprogress' does not exist on type 'FileTransferObject'.

Comment: p of progress should be uppercase: onProgress

Answer (score 0):

More something like this:

```
fileTransfer.onProgress((progressEvent) => {
    var percent =  progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100;
    this.percentage = Math.round(percent);
    console.log(this.percentage);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**.ts File:**

```
  const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

  fileTransfer.onProgress((progressEvent: ProgressEvent): void => {
    this.uploadStatus = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 
    100);
    console.log("Upload Progress () => ", this.uploadStatus);
    console.log("progressEvent.loaded ", progressEvent.loaded);
    console.log("progressEvent.total ", progressEvent.total);
  });
```

**.html File:**

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-label class="upload-video-label"> Progress... {{uploadStatus}}%
  </ion-label>
</ion-row>
```